# Apply a formula to particular cells in Microsoft Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, macros, spreadsheet

Say I have the following sheet:

```
  |  A   |  B  |  C  |  
1 |  5   |  1  |  5  |    
2 |  8   |  8  |  99 |
3 |  77  |  3  |  3  |
4 |  2   |  7  |  4  |
5 |      |     |     |
6 | Base:|  2  |     |
```

Now I want to apply such a 'formula' to the cells mentioned about : `=LOG(<cell>, B6)`, where `<cell>` is obviously the cell value of the above cells.  Obviously, the `B6` should remain as it is.

How can I do this without the copy and pasting?

**Update**: The problem with putting the formula in the first cell and dragging down is that the `B6` gets incremented to `B7`, `B8` etc, but I want it to stay as `B6`

Comment: "cell number of the above cells"? Do you mean cell values?

Comment: Yup, cell values.  I updated the question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Enter the formula into the first cell, and then click and drag the black square on the bottom right of the cell to cover all the cells you want to contain the formula. Excel is clever enough to update the cell references appropriately as it copies the formula.

---

**Edit** You want to add dollar symbols before both parts of the static cell:

```
LOG(<cell>, $B$6)
```

Comment: Updated the question.  The problem is that the `B6` value is changed when u drag downwards

Comment: Ah, I see, answer updated.

Answer (score 2):

If you want `B6` to stay the same in all the cells after you drag, write `$B$6` instead.

The dollar sign preceding row or column references prevents them from being updated when drag-copying the formula.

Answer (score 0):

replace  with the cell reference,

e.g.

```
=LOG(A3, 10)
```

or

```
=LOG(A1:A5, 10)
```

for a range

Comment: But I want every cell to contain the formula for itself