# Microsoft Excel applies formula wrongly

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

Basically I am facing a problem due to Excel auto generate formula that is wrong in such situation.  The formula at `B6` is `=A6*B1`. 
I select this and drag/fill down. 
I want the formula in `B7` to refer to `A7`
and the formula in `B8` to refer to `A8`, etc.,
but I want them all to have `*B1`.

But, when I use the cursor drag down, the formula is applied as:

```
=A7*B2
=A8*B3
=A9*B4
```

I want all of the cells to be multiplied by `B1` and not have it increment.

How can I accomplish this?

[image: here's the image]

Answer (score 6):

Change the formula in `B6` to `=A6*$B$1` (note the `$`'s) This makes the reference to B1 absolute.

Now when you drag it down, the reference to B1 does not change.

For more details, google *excel absolute relative reference*

Comment: +1 This is by far the best response. Only thing that could make it better might be an active link to something like [About Cell and Range References](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/about-cell-and-range-references-HP005198323.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

In the paste special menu select Multiply and you are done!

Comment: The comparison “a picture is worth 1000 words” is best used in moderation. This answer has ***way*** too few words. It’s nearly impossible to see what cells you’re referencing in the first two images because you cropped off the column headers and the row labels. The third image isn’t very helpful because the menus completely obscure the data. Finally, from what I can figure out that you’re saying, I believe that it’s not really what the OP wants.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, I will take into account this when writing an answer next.

Answer (score -1):

By dragging down to the bottom excel autofill's B1 as in numbering to make it B2, B3, B4
What you can do is for every calculation you can do it manually select B1 e.g
=A7*B1 ... this is what you do type = then select A7 type * then select B1 ... then press enter

Comment: no other faster way? I got hundred of rows..

Comment: oh, I just found the solution, btw, thanks for your reply too. http://superuser.com/questions/113292/apply-a-formula-to-particular-cells-in-microsoft-excel

Comment: @Dima - Would you even consider using this for a worksheet with a dozen columns of 100K rows that require formulas?